# No migrations to apply. I got this error in test

Tags: python, django

I got an error when I do test,

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, app, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

I wrote in test.py

```
class UserModelTests(TestCase):
    def test_is_empty(self):
        queryset = User.objects.order_by('user_id').values()[:2]
        expected = [
            {'name': 'Tom', 'user_id': 1, 'nationarity': 'America', 'dormitory': 'A', 'group': 3}
        ]
        for idx, item in enumerate(expected):
            self.assertDictEqual(item, queryset[idx])
```

I read documents and other web site, I found fixtures & setUp() are needed maybe, but I cannot understand how to write it.How should I fix this?What should I add to this code?
 I use command `./manage.py test` .

Comment: What command are you using to run the tests? You'll need to add that to the question. Cheers

Comment: @mightyspaj I use command `./manage.py test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not facing an error, but a response of the database migrations being applied (non in your case). If you would use the `./manage.py migrate` command, you would see the same response.

When you make modifications to your model structures, you must must call the `./manage.py makemigrations` command. These `makemigrations` creates a migration file in your `app/migrations` directory. Those files are used
to apply the new migrations to the actual database (or revert to a previous state).

The message `No migrations to apply` means that there are non of these migrations files left that are not applied to the database yet. When the command is called, the migrations will be executed for the modules listed in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

If the tests have been executed and an assertion failed, test error would look something like:

```
Testing started at 9:45 ...
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/edwin/git/portfolio/backend/apps/projects/tests.py", line 114, in test_project_link_datetime_modified_on_update
    self.assertNotEqual(None, None)
AssertionError: None == None

Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Process finished with exit code 1
```

A successful test might look like:

```
./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
........................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 24 tests in 0.208s

OK
```

If you are not seeing any of these, you are most likely not performing your tests properly. Be sure that you have added your app containing these tests is added to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file. Try running the test as `./manage.py test` or for a particular app you can use `./manage.py test <app_name>`